# And and OR query in cakephp

Tags: sql, cakephp

i am new to cakephp and want this query-

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE   id=1 
        AND (country=INDIA OR country=JAPAN OR country=KOREA)
```

Comment: I answer your question, but, this condition is not a good condition, At least it is just an example

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->YourModel->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'id' => 1, 
        'country' => array('INDIA', 'JAPAN', 'KOREA')
)));
```

Comment: thanks for replying but this is fetching data having INDIA country, it is not considering KOREA and JAPAN

Comment: The code is fine and I think it consider three of them but the error might be not because of the country selection, may be it is because of the "id = 1", It means there might not be any data which is id = 1 and country Japan nor Korea

Answer (score 2):

Read a little more [Retrieving Your Data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) for understand better the syntax, try with that:

```
$countries = $this->Country->find('all', array(
       'conditions' => array(
           'id' => 1,
           'OR' => array(
               array('name' => 'INDIA'),
               array('name' => 'KOREA'),
               array('name' => 'JAPAN'),
           )
        )
    ));
```

Comment: no need for the 'AND' array - move the 'OR' up one level.

Comment: @Dave Thank's. Fixed it.